# 403 forbidden error while accessing magento connect manager in magento 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-connect-manager, http-status-403

I got 403 error in magento 1.8 admin while I trying to access **magento connect manager** under **configuration->tools**

[image]

I also try to re-save administration roles under **configuration->permissions->roles** . What should I need to do overcome this error ?

Comment: check .htaccess file in downloader directory. 
I think IP will be restricted in that. or else once replace htaccess from original magento's htaccess. so it will work.

Comment: let me check @DhavalSolankiDrcsystems

Comment: yes, you are right problem was in .htaccess file in downloader directory. Thank u @DhavalSolankiDrcsystems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check .htaccess file in downloader directory. I think IP will be restricted in that. or else once replace htaccess from original magento's htaccess. so it will work.